# Static analysis not working on simplest possible example

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, code-contracts

The following is an example I have created in order to get the static analysis tool to fail:

```
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            object x = null;
            Contract.Assert(x != null);
        }
    }
}
```

Runtime analysis throws the correct exception but static analysis builds without even a warning. I have every checkbox selected in the project settings, and the warning level on "hi". I am running version 1.4.51019.0.

What do I need to do to get compilation to fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Every checkbox selected" is the problem here. You need to uncheck "Infer Ensures".

What happens here is the following:
The code you created can never be correct, you initialize `x` with `null` and directly afterwards you assert that `x` should be not `null`.
Because of this contradiction, Code Contracts inferes `Contract.Ensures(false)`, which will always fail.
I assume that the infered `Contract.Ensures(false)` at the beginning of the method will make the static analyser skip the rest of the method.

Infering `Contract.Ensures(false)` seems like a mistake of Code Contracts to me, but the only way to disable it is to disable the inference of ensures completely.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick (need to wait to accept the answer)

Comment: Should I also uncheck the other "Infers" boxes?

Comment: @AlexG: I only leave "Infer invariants for read-only" checked in my projects.